# Unable to submit for review

Tags: facebook

when I click on "Start a submission" I get a popup (attached) saying , select the item you want to include in this submission  where a red mark is shown against  App Details- English (Us)  and does not let me include anything.

[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG5vA.png)

-regards
 Ma!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hover on the red mark, you'll see the actual issue. It says-

[image]

Facebook needs some enough ratings/ engagement before you can submit the app for the App Center. There's no such numbers it all just depends on facebook when they'll allow you for submission.